# Grace period after second study period in USA?

Tags: visas, international-travel, f1-visas

I've enrolled in a language school in the US for six months. I have an F-1 visa. I know that after six months I have a 60 day grace period.

If I decide to register at another school for example three months do I have one more 60-day grace period?

Also during my grace period I can't go to any other country like Canada, Mexico... can I?

Comment: What citizenship do you have? Does your visa say multiple entry?

Answer (score 2):

If you decide stay for another course & get a visa extension, you'll be able to get the 60 days grace period again.
But, during the grace period, it never allowed in any country to leave & return. The grace period visas are for a travelers facilitation in helping him decide if he/she is going to stay longer or not.
So, these grace period can't be multiple entry visas.